# bash Print line per line consecutive numbers with separator

Tags: linux, bash, shell

this is the problem:

I have an input file, like this

```
000064152|737636807|1502190508
000064152|737636807|1502190508
000064152|737636807|1502190508
000064152|737636807|1502190508
000064152|737636807|1502190508
000150323|153768429|1504172028
...
..
.
```

and i have to obtain this result

```
1&&000064152|737636807|1502190508
2&&000064152|737636807|1502190508
3&&000064152|737636807|1502190508
4&&000064152|737636807|1502190508
5&&000064152|737636807|1502190508
6&&000150323|153768429|1504172028
...
..
.
```

Comment: Please help....

Comment: What script do you currently have now?

Comment: What have you tried so far? "Please help" isn't a specific question.

Comment: Paste your code first so we can help~

Comment: @ArnoldDelgado Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is a forum for "questions". It is expected you have a "question" in your post. You can edit your post and add a ex. `How do I output a file with leading numbers separated by a custom string?` and also edit the title of your question. What have you tried? What research did you make? Please include relevant info. How is the input file named? How is the output file named? Did you at least searched [google how to number lines in file in bash](https://www.google.pl/search?q=how+to+number+lines+in+file+in+bash)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the job for [`nl` - number lines of files](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nl.1.html):

```
nl -s'&&' -w1 input_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use `awk` (which should be available by default), you can do this:

```
awk '{print NR"&&"$0}' file
```

If you provide more specific details in your question, I could modify this based on relevancy

Answer (score 0):

another way :

```
i=0; while read line; do echo $((i+=1))"&&""$line";done < input_file
```